# Scrolling Functionality

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, gridview, scrollview

I need to implement a UI like this:

[image]

In the above screen `row needs to be scrolled horizontally` and `columns need to be scrolled vertically`.

I have not used Gallery as It is being deprecated. Here are some scenarios which I have tried:

**1.** Combination of GridView and ListView.

**2.** Combination of ListView and Horizontal ListView(Custom Component).

`Option 1` did not work for me but I could make it with `option 2`.
With option 2 perfomance is not good.

**Solution:** I am thinking of implementing `4-5 horizontal listviews inside scrollview with Gestures` so that I can handle the vertical swipe thru code or by `subclassing the ScrollView and overriding the onScrollChanged method`.

But I am looking for some more optimized solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone with my solution if anyone can suggest a better solution then obviously I will go with it:

**Solution:**

> Implemented 4-5 horizontal listviews inside scrollview with Gestures
>   and handled the vertical swipe thru code or by subclassing the
>   ScrollView and overriding the onScrollChanged method.

Answer (score 1):

Use webview and push the content into it through JS hooks.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time, +1 for that but I need to do it with android components not with html, jScript.